# Removing items from a list when I find a value

Tags: ocaml

I have this list:

```
let myList = [(1,2,0);(1,3,0);(1,4,0);(2,6,0);(3,5,0);(4,6,0);(6,5,0);(6,7,0);(5,4,0)];;
```

I want to remove each element in list when the first position is equals with a number, for example if I remove the element starts with 1 the result must be this:

```
[(2,6,0);(3,5,0);(4,6,0);(6,5,0);(6,7,0);(5,4,0)];;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OCaml's [standard library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfilter):

```
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
(** filter p l returns all the elements of the list l that satisfy 
    the predicate p. The order of the elements in the input list is
    preserved. *)
```

The following function will compare a first element of a triple with a constant number `n`

```
let first_is n (m,_,_) = n = m
```

Then you can use this to filter your list:

```
List.filter (first_is 1) [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
```

This will remove all elements that doesn't satisfy the predicate, i.e., in the given example it will return a list with only one triple: `[1,2,3]`.

Since you want the opposite, then you can define predicate:

```
let first_isn't n (m,_,_) = n <> m
```

A full example in the interactive toplevel:

```
# let xs = [1,2,0;1,3,0;1,4,0;2,6,0;3,5,0;4,6,0;6,5,0;6,7,0;5,4,0];;
val xs : (int * int * int) list =
  [(1, 2, 0); (1, 3, 0); (1, 4, 0); (2, 6, 0); (3, 5, 0); (4, 6, 0);
   (6, 5, 0); (6, 7, 0); (5, 4, 0)]
# let first_isn't n (m,_,_) = n <> m;;
val first_isn't : 'a -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> bool = <fun>
# List.filter (first_isn't 1) xs;;
- : (int * int * int) list =
[(2, 6, 0); (3, 5, 0); (4, 6, 0); (6, 5, 0); (6, 7, 0); (5, 4, 0)]
```